# Changing img src javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to swap images on my page using javascript, I have several products with thumbs of each, when the thumbs are clicked the main images is changed. but...when I add more than one product it changes both. they have separate id's but it is still changing both... here is the script in the head

```
  function changeImage(imgName)
  {
     image = document.getElementById('numberone');
     image.src = imgName;
     image = document.getElementById('othertwo');
     image.src = imgName;
 }
```

Html

```
<img src="images/products/vests/classy_clay_beige_vest_front.JPG" alt="beige" width="350" height="400" id="numberone">
```

and the thumbs

```
<div class="thumb1">
     <img src="images/products/vests/classy_clay_beige_vest_front_thumb.JPG" alt="beige" width="80" height="91" onclick="changeImage('images/products/vests/classy_clay_beige_vest_front.JPG')">
</div>
<div class="thumb2">
    <img src="images/products/vests/classy_clay_beige_vest_back_thumb.JPG" alt="navy" width="80" height="91" onclick="changeImage('images/products/vests/classy_clay_beige_vest_back.JPG')">
</div>
```

[Link to website](http://rkshootingsupply.com/test/classy-clays-vests)

Comment: Change the second image variable to something else you are using it twice

Comment: I think it seems to be working. Maybe the image is large and just waiting for the download to finish before the image is updated.

Comment: @ysrb it is not working. on clicking a thumbnail, both product-previews are updated, not just the one under which you clicked the thumnail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the update image function updates all product-previews, you will need to pass in the id of the product preview you want to update like so:

```
onclick="changeImage("numberone",'images/products/vests/classy_clay_beige_vest_front.JPG')"
```

and replace the update function with this.

```
changeImage(id,url){
    image = document.getElementById(id);
    image.src = url;
}
```

in order to add more products easier, you could just use a consistent class, and use the order they appear on the page. so that the first one would be `document.getElementsByClassName("thumb-large")[0]` and so on. then instead of passing in the id, you would pass in the reference.

Comment: I think you need to update the onclick to be:
onclick="changeImage('numberone','images/products/vests/classy_clay_beige_vest_front.JPG')"

Comment: @Mobius I replaced the function and added the id to the onclick now its not working at all...

Comment: I think the problem is that i used double qotes, change the onclick("numberone" to onclick('numberone'

Comment: @Mobius changed it again still not working at all...?

Comment: so i apparently named the function chageImage instead of changeImage. you will need to rename it. I tested it in the console, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

With a minor restructure, and using jQuery (which you tagged the question), this would work for you:

```
<img src="images/products/vests/classy_clay_beige_vest_front.JPG" alt="beige" width="350" height="400" id="numberone">

<div class="thumbs">
    <div class="thumb1">
        <img src="images/products/vests/classy_clay_beige_vest_front_thumb.JPG" alt="beige" width="80" height="91" data-large-src="images/products/vests/classy_clay_beige_vest_front.JPG">
    </div>
    <div class="thumb2">
        <img src="images/products/vests/classy_clay_beige_vest_back_thumb.JPG" alt="navy" width="80" height="91" data-large-src="changeImage('images/products/vests/classy_clay_beige_vest_back.JPG">
    </div>
</div>

jQuery(function($) {
    $('div.thumbs img').click(
        function() {
               $('#numberone').attr('src', ($(this).attr('data-large-src'));
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want some swapping like this?

Please check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/37w7a/1/).

```
$(".thumb").click(function(){
 var tmp=$(this).find("img").attr("src");
 $("#numberone").attr("src",tmp);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is cleaner if you write your code like below.

```
 function changeImage(imgName)
  {
     document.getElementById('numberone').src = imgName;
     document.getElementById('othertwo').src = imgName;
 };
```

The less script you've got to write the better so that when the request for the .js file or html file with the JavaScript embedded is severed to the client the payload is lighter.